Увеличение элементов формы при импорте в Visual Studio 2019
Я пытаюсь перенести свой проект из .NET Framework 4.7.8 на .NET Core 3.1 в VS 2019.
При импорте формы в новый проект я сталкиваюсь с проблемой: размеры элементов на форме изменяются, и новые размеры записываются в свойство Size. Это происходит именно при импорте формы, а не в процессе выполнения приложения.
Я пробовал настроить различные параметры DPI и AutoScaleMode, но это не решило проблему. Какие ещё шаги можно предпринять для предотвращения изменения размеров элементов при импорте формы и сохранения оригинальных размеров?

Точный совет дать не могу, но могу дать несколько полезных ссылок: Migration guide, Upgrade Assistant, Upgrade .NET FW WinForms to .NET 8

А почему .NET Core 3.1? Это уже устаревшая версия. Сейчас в ходу .NET 8. В ноябре выходит .NET 9.

[А почему .NET Core 3.1?]
Только что попробовал на VS 2022 .NET 8.0. Та же самая проблема.

Прикол. Поставил this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None; в InitializeComponent() формы и при импорте уже ничего не увеличивается (сохраняются исходные размеры). Я думал этот код только для исполнения, но видимо VS считывает при импорте информацию отсюда и если явно указано "не масштабировать" то пересчёт не выполняется.
Осталось только найти как вообще отключить такое поведение, в чём его причина . Но даже так проблему можно считать закрытой

[несколько полезных ссылок] - спасибо. Думаю миграция там не потребуется, очень уж простой проект. В моём случае несколько форм перенести нужно просто и какая-то галочка в настройках мешает сделать это быстро). Ну хоть такой вариант (выше) нашелся.
